# Swift with Material Alert (MDCAlertController) - how to override size?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, material-design, uialertcontroller

In Swift 4, I'm looking for a way to overwrite **`MDCAlertController`** size. I'm creating alert with code like this:

```
import MaterialComponents.MaterialDialogs

let alertController = MDCAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "message")
alertController.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.2, green: 0.2, blue: 0.2, alpha: 1.0)
alertController.titleColor = .white
alertController.messageColor = .white
```

Tried to set it's size with:

```
alertController.view.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 200)
```

but it takes no effect in resulting alertbox.

Trying to set `alertController.frame.width` gives me warning that it's a get-only property. Is there a way to set this component size?

Comment: Have you tried `alertController.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 200)` ? The properties of a frame are get-only, but that isn't true for the frame itself.

Comment: @Eric Yeah, but got warning: `Value of type 'MDCAlertController' has no member 'frame'`. If you meant `alertController.view.frame..` than this also does not take effect in resulting alertbox size